# Indicator of multiple values in previous obs by group (time series)

Tags: r, data.table, time-series

Using data.table with data structure something like:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(12345)
dt <- data.table(id = c(rep('A',6),rep('B',3),rep('C',5),'D'), 
             day = c(rep(11:15,3)),
             drug = sample(LETTERS[4:6], 15, replace = TRUE))
setkey(dt,'id','day')
```

resulting data.table `dt`:

```
     id day drug
 1:  A   11    F
 2:  A   11    D
 3:  A   12    F
 4:  A   13    F
 5:  A   14    F
 6:  A   15    E
 7:  B   12    D
 8:  B   13    E
 9:  B   14    F
10:  C   11    D
11:  C   12    D
12:  C   13    F
13:  C   14    D
14:  C   15    F
15:  D   15    E
```

I am trying to generate a logical variable describing whether each subject, denoted by `id`, has been on >1 `drug` in a time interval ranging from the current `day` to 2 `day`s prior to the current observation.

Thus, the desired modified data.table would be:

```
    id  day drug    poly
 1:  A   11    F    TRUE
 2:  A   11    D    TRUE
 3:  A   12    F    TRUE
 4:  A   13    F    TRUE
 5:  A   14    F    FALSE
 6:  A   15    E    TRUE
 7:  B   12    D    FALSE
 8:  B   13    E    TRUE
 9:  B   14    F    TRUE
10:  C   11    D    FALSE
11:  C   12    D    FALSE
12:  C   13    F    TRUE
13:  C   14    D    TRUE
14:  C   15    F    TRUE
15:  D   15    E    FALSE
```

I'm not wedded to `data.table`, but am working with very large data (~23M rows), so solution must be memory efficient or I max out RAM.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. This is far from a bad question in the context of all of stackoverflow.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks, wasn't sure what could have been clearer, but i am new and open to any constructive criticism for improving clarity or concision.

Comment: The example data is good and the question is pretty clear. The only thing lacking which some people like to see is an attempt at solving the problem with your own code, but that's not such a huge problem if you don't know where to start.

Comment: When the day is "11", why is it TRUE? past 2 days includes current day as well? Should "11" then check for days "10, 11"?

Comment: @Arun I have edited the question to try to clarify the question in accordance with your point. As I hope the edit makes clear, when the current row day = 11, function should check days 11, 10 and 9 (ie, current and two previous). If you can make this more lucid please edit or suggest text and I will.

Comment: @Rtisan, could you provide some more info on your real data dimensions - how many columns? how many unique `id`s, `day`s and `drug`s do you've in your dataset? Better yet, if you could provide some code to generate artificial data of your dimensions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better, more `data.table` centric way, but this works:

```
dt[, 
  poly := sapply(
    lapply(day, function(y) (y - day) %in% 0:2), 
    function(z) length(unique(drug[z])) > 1), 
  by=id
  ]

#    id day drug  poly
# 1:  A   9    F  TRUE
# 2:  A   9    D  TRUE
# 3:  A  10    F  TRUE
# 4:  A  11    F  TRUE
# 5:  A  12    F FALSE
# 6:  A  13    E  TRUE
# 7:  B  10    D FALSE
# 8:  B  11    E  TRUE
# 9:  B  12    F  TRUE
#10:  C   9    D FALSE
#11:  C  10    D FALSE
#12:  C  11    F  TRUE
#13:  C  12    D  TRUE
#14:  C  13    F  TRUE
#15:  D  13    E FALSE
```

Comment: helpful solution. generates desired results and runs on 23M rows in <20 minutes. given the speed of many other `:=` data.table operations (which run on same data in seconds), it seems possible that a faster solution exists, but this one is solid.

Comment: @Rtisan - I was hoping it would run quicker than 20 minutes. Wow. There must be a better solution but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: @Arun - there must be a quicker way to do this? Maybe via merging data.tables?

Comment: @thelatemail, dint get a message on your tag, not sure why. Yes, I thought of trying something at the time, but then he accepted the answer. Figured it's good. Will write an answer if I manage.